# Regex for containig at least one latin character

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

i'm having a regex that is allowing only Latin letters and numbers and allows the symbols `@`, `_` and `.`. The final requirement is that it must contain at least one Latin letter.

My regex is this:

```
const regTest = /^([0-9A-Za-z_@.])+$/g;
```

Comment: Step 1: remove the `g` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with following regex:

```
/^[0-9a-z_@.]*[a-z][0-9a-z_@.]*$/i
```

Comment: I'd go with `/^[\d_@.]*[a-z][\w@.]*$/i`

Answer (score 2):

You may also try with the usage of positive lookahead:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])[\w@\.]*$
```

Use with ignore case flag.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nvnN1x/2)

Comment: You put a `+` in character class but it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Oh missed that, thanks.

Comment: Upvoted and to avoid backtracks you could do `^(?=[^a-z\s]*[a-z])[\w@.]+$` instead of an evil greedy dot.